# Parallelising python for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, multiprocessing

I am attempting to parallelise some code in python. Running in serial my code takes around 24 hours, however, there is a for loop where each iteration is independent of the previous iteration, so this is an ideal situation for parallelisation. A simple example of what I am trying to achieve with my code is as follows,

```
import scipy as sci
from multiprocessing import Pool

def mycode(args):
  for x in range(0,2000)
    y = sci.fft(data[x,:],axis=1)
    output[x,:]=y
  return output

if __name__=="__main__":
  pool=Pool(processes = 8)
  output= pool.map(mycode(args),2000)
```

However, from looking at top, I can see that although python generates 9 python processes, only one is actually using any CPU power or memory. All the others are at 0%. What is the correct way to use Pool with a for loop?

Comment: What is the `reconstruction` function? Does it return a callable? Why is the second argument to `pool.map` a number (2000) and not an iterable? Why is there a `mycode` function in your example if it is never called?

Comment: with iterable arguement as 2000 it will only use 1 process.

Answer (score 1):

As long as this data variable has been defined as global, this should work.

```
import scipy as sci
from multiprocessing import Pool

def mycode(x):
    y = sci.fft(data[x,:],axis=1)
    return y

if __name__=="__main__":
  pool=Pool(processes = 8)
  output= pool.map(mycode,range(2000))
```